# Identify a specific font

Tags: fonts

I would like to identify the font in the following text (have tried with several websites with no success):

[image]

Thanks

Comment: if you have the pdf you can list the fonts exactly, you don't have to make people guess from an image

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz No, I already tried those methods.

Comment: @PedroGarcía Did you try to look up the used fonts from the pdf?

Comment: @PedroGarcía can you show the output from `pdffonts`? That should answer your question

Comment: looking at https://www.studocu.com/en-gb/document/the-university-of-warwick/galois-theory/ma3d5-2008-2009-lecture-notes-3-field-extensions/1213177  shows URW Palladio L Italic, CMR10, URW Palladio L Roman

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'd say that the math font is indeed Palladio (except for the double-struck Q maybe), but the body text looks more like ITC Charter. But it is hard to tell from just seeing this JPEG ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht see my link above you can't download the pdf from there but the html browser dom inspector lets you see the font of any character, I selected a bit of math and did "inspect" in firefox and looked at the fonts tab

Comment: @JasperHabicht selecting some body text it's Bitstream Charter :-)

Comment: @JasperHabicht the |Q  is `dsrom12`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Cool, that's a nice way to inspect a PDF actually! I should have followed the link directly ...